# Encrypting app's local files

Tags: android, security, encryption

I'm currently writing a banking app. A lot of information is cached on the device in order to access it without a delay. This information include sensible data like information about a bank account (e.g. holder name, bank name, bank account number or the current balance, but no transaction data). These informations are stored in a file generated by `Context#openFileOutput(String, int)` using `Context#MODE_PRIVATE`. I would like to further protect this information by encrypting it.

My question is: What would be a appropriate key for the symmetrical encryption? I thought about using the PIN which is needed to access the app, but then I could not implement the fingerprint reader because I do not get the PIN from it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check out facebook's conceal lib.

https://facebook.github.io/conceal/